# LDAP authorization not working in Gerrit

Tags: ldap, gerrit

After installing Gerrit and configuring it to use LDAP while authenticating GUI, I'm having a problem with groups authorization. I provided the code review +2 role to LDAP group however users within this group can't +2. Actually users are treated as normal registered users with +1 ability.

Here are my Gerrit configs:

```
[auth] 
type = LDAP 
gitBasicAuth = true 
[ldap] 
server = ldap://IP:Port 
username = username 
password = password 
accountBase = accountBase
groupBase = groupBase 
referral = follow accountPattern = (sAMAccountName=${username})
groupPattern = (cn=${groupname})
accountFullName = displayName
accountMemberField = member
accountEmailAddress = mail
groupMemberPattern = (&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(member=${groupname}))
```

Here are the project configuration:

```
[access "refs/for/refs/*"]
push = group ldap/Group Name
submit = group ldap/Group Name
owner = group ldap/Group Name
pushMerge = group ldap/Group Name
[access "refs/heads/*"]
label-Code-Review = -2..+2 group ldap/Group Name
submit = group ldap/Group Name
push = group ldap/Group Name
owner = group ldap/Group Name
forgeAuthor = group ldap/Group Name
```